# pyinstaller with matlab : ImportError No module named 'mlarray'

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to package my script with pyinstaller. My script interacts with matlab, so matlab python API is imported. I got below error when i run the executable file.

---

### ImportError No module named 'mlarray'

The problem is on importing mlarray module, so I did an experiment on a simplest script as below.

```
from matlab import mlarray
```

Then, I package it with pyinstaller. I got the same error as expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVIMJ.jpg)

Anyone met the same problem with me?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing

From

```
from _internal.mlarray_sequence import _MLArrayMetaClass
```

to

```
from matlab._internal.mlarray_sequence import _MLArrayMetaClass
```

in
\Python36\Lib\site-packages\matlab\mlarray.py

And

From

```
from _internal.mlarray_utils import _get_strides, _get_size, \
    _normalize_size, _get_mlsize, _reshape
```

To

```
from matlab._internal.mlarray_utils import _get_strides, _get_size, \
    _normalize_size, _get_mlsize, _reshape
```

In
\Python36\Lib\site-packages\matlab_internal\mlarray_sequence.py

And adding hiddenimports=['scipy._lib.messagestream'] to the spec file

Comment: I can confirm this works, you have to read the errors that your printing to your MatLab console and fix them in the MatLab python modules to be able to compile the code. I had another issue where I needed to specify a path for a text file, as well as the ones in this answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove the changes to matlab.

Then create a directory structure - and the hook-matlab.py file - like the following tree:

- script_to_compile.py  # This is the python file you run pyinstaller on
- hooks  # DIR

  - hook-matlab.py
    And inside of hook-matlab.py:

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('matlab')
Then build with the extra option --additional-hooks-dir=hooks.